# Uploading a txt with discord.py on_message()

Tags: python, file, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to send a text file with discord.py through an on_message() event. So far the most I've done is this:

```
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as fp:
  await message.channel.send(file=discord.file(fp, 'TestFile'))
```

(I obviously started the bot and the on_message event works).

Whenever this runs though it gives an error saying "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable". The "module" in this situation is `import discord`. I've been stuck on this issue for **2 days** now and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you please provide a full code sample, the code given in this post is not enough to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for [`discord.File`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=file#discord.File), not `discord.file`.

```py
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as fp:
  await message.channel.send(file=discord.File(fp, 'TestFile'))
```

If you were to do a bit of experimentation...

```py
>>> import discord
>>> type(discord.file)
<class 'module`>
>>> type(discord.File)
<class 'type'>
>>>
```

... you would see that, yes, `discord.file` is a module, while you are looking for `discord.File`, the type.

Comment: THANK YOU. I've been stumped on this for so long because of something this trivial, I cannot explain in words how grateful I am. I can't believe the capitalization of a single letter bamboozled me for the past 2 days. Thanks for such a quick answer as well, it means a lot.

Comment: @AverageLua No problems! It happens to the best of us.